# dynatree column layout css not working

Tags: css, dynatree

Dynatree has an example of column layout [here](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/test-table.html).

I am trying the same but cant make it to work.
Can anyone suggest a better css plan for columns ?

[My JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/G9VKL/)

```
//output sample after proper clomun layout
// Motors      Parts(12253)      STOCK(12)      Collection(5)
// BIKES       Parts(12253)      STOCK(12)      Collection(5)
// BICYCLES    Parts(12253)      STOCK(12)      Collection(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 #table {display: table;}
.row {display: table-row;}
.cell {display: table-cell;width:100px;}

<div id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="cell">Parts(12253)</span>
     <span class="cell">STOCK(12)</span>v
     <span class="cell">Collection(5)</span>
  </div>  
</div>
```